# How to Close a DataReader on Exception

Tags: c#, .net-1.1, sqldatareader, sqlcommand

I have the following code in some methods of my Data Layer:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
SqlCommand s = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), conn);
try 
{ 
    SqlDataReader dr = s.ExecuteReader(); 
    while(dr.Read())
      DoSomething(dr);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ 
    sb.Append(Util.ExceptionRecursive(ex)); 
}
```

The thing is, dr never closes in case of exception. And when other method tries to access another data reader, it throws another exception that says something like *"Another Datareader is connected to the Database"*

I want to close my DataReader in any case. 
But this:

```
sb = new StringBuilder();
SqlCommand s = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), conn);
SqlDataReader dr;
try 
{
    dr = s.ExecuteReader(); 
    while(dr.Read())
      DoSomething(dr);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ 
    sb.Append(Util.ExceptionRecursive(ex)); 
}
finally
{
    dr.Close();
}
```

Won't work because in case of exception dr may have no data, and won't compile.

How should I do it then?

Comment: You should use a `ConnectionStringBuilder`  **EDIT**: (if you're building a connection string)

Comment: @Lasse: For the connection string.  (I thought he was creating a SqlConnection too)

Comment: You should probably be using parameters

Comment: conn is a SqlConnection, already made.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):
It generates a `finally` block to ensure that your resource is always disposed.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (SqlCommand s = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), conn)) {
    try 
    { 

        using (SqlDataReader dr = s.ExecuteReader()) {
            while(dr.Read())
              DoSomething(dr);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        sb.Append(Util.ExceptionRecursive(ex)); 
    }    
}
```

Comment: what internally would the using do? Dispose or Close? If it's Dispose,  will it "remember" to Close the DataReader?

Comment: @apacay: `Dispose()` calls `Close()`.  You should use a separate `using` statement per object.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is probably this:

```
sb = new StringBuilder();
...
using (SqlCommand s = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), conn))
using (SqlDataReader dr = s.ExecuteReader())
{
    try
    {
        while(dr.Read())
          DoSomething(dr);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        sb.Append(Util.ExceptionRecursive(ex)); 
    }
}
```

However, if you're expecting (or not) exceptions during SQL execution, you must place the exception handling code outside:

```
sb = new StringBuilder();
...
try
{
    using (SqlCommand s = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), conn))
    using (SqlDataReader dr = s.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(dr.Read())
          DoSomething(dr);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ 
    sb.Append(Util.ExceptionRecursive(ex)); 
}
```

Comment: But it all depends on where you expect exceptions.

Comment: Exceptions generally come from `ExecuteReader`, not `Read`.

Comment: They could come from `DoSomething`, but I agree, edited the answer

Comment: @Lasse my problem comes from the ExecuteReader... `DoSomething(SqlDataReader dr)` shouldn't cause any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

you can write it as:

```
if(dr!=null) dr.Close();
```

Comment: I thought of that but it seemed unclean clean to me.